# Instana monitoring inside docker swarm cluster?

Tags: docker, monitoring, docker-swarm, instana

I'm trying to monitor a springboot microservice with instana on a docker swarm cluster. the Microservice has 2 replicas per node on a 3 nodes cluster. it is possible? do i need to run instana agent image with docker run? docker service? any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know the post it's pretty old but I wondering if you have tried to installing instana on Docker if NOT please do follow this documentation : [Instana Docker](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/obi/current?topic=installer-container-based-installation#minimum-requirements)
I hope that will help achieve the above you already mentioned.